# What is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha =\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

What is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha =\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ over finite field $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$?
I first think that it is the $f(x)=x^{2}-x-1$, but $f(x)$ is the reducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$. Help please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $\Bbb Z_5$ is the integers modulo $5$ then $\sqrt5=0$ in $\Bbb Z_5$ surely?

Comment: Why is $f(x)$ reducible?

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}_5$ mean the integers mod $5$ or the $5$-adic integers?

Comment: $2\alpha-1=-\sqrt5\equiv0\pmod5$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think the usual definition requires minimal polynomials to be monic, so you should multiply your answer by $3$.

Comment: So then $\alpha-3$;  note that $(x-3)^2=x^2-6x+9\equiv x^2-x-1\pmod5$

Comment: ah ha! Thank you everyone!

Comment: So the conclusion is that the minimal polynomial is $x-3$, right?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the $\Bbb Z$-minimal polynomial for $\frac{1-\sqrt5}2$ is $x^2-x-1$. If by “$\Bbb Z_5$” you mean the five-adic integers, this is still the minimal polynomial over that ring.

But you probably mean $\Bbb Z_5=\Bbb Z/(5)$, the prime field of order $5$. In that case, take the polynomial above and notice that
$$
x^2-x-1\equiv(x-3)^2\pmod5\,.
$$
Accordingly, your minimal polynomial should be just $x-3$, as many of the commenters have already said.